# Populating the data for future months

Tags: amazon-redshift

My requirement is to populate the data for the missing months using amazon-redshift query.

The below data is getting populated using the below query
`SELECT CASE
         WHEN data.country = '' THEN 'DEFAULTVALUE'
         ELSE UPPER(data.country)
       END AS country_name,
         product.product_client AS brand,
       product.product_name,
       geography.brick,
       product.product_id,
       product.period,
       units
       FROM rdb.tgt_ims_mktshare_data data
  INNER JOIN dwh.DMN_GEOGRAPHY geography
          ON UPPER (data.country) = UPPER (COALESCE (geography.country_name,'DEFAULTVALUE'))
         AND UPPER (data.study) = UPPER (COALESCE (geography.study,'DEFAULTVALUE'))
         AND UPPER (COALESCE (data.geo_lowest_level,'DEFAULTVALUE')) = UPPER (COALESCE (geography.brick,'DEFAULTVALUE'))
         AND UPPER (DECODE (data.Prescription_Origin,'','DEFAULTVALUE',data.Prescription_Origin)) = UPPER (COALESCE (geography.Prescription_Origin,'DEFAULTVALUE'))
  INNER JOIN dwh.DMN_PRODUCT_EMEA product
          ON UPPER (data.country) = UPPER (COALESCE (product.country_name,'DEFAULTVALUE'))
         AND UPPER (product.product_name) = UPPER (COALESCE (data.product,'DEFAULTVALUE'))
         AND UPPER (COALESCE (NULLIF (product.pack_name,''),'DEFAULTVALUE')) = UPPER (COALESCE (NULLIF (data.pack,''),'DEFAULTVALUE'))
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dwh.DMN_TIME period ON period.period::DATE = data.period::DATE
ORDER BY period DESC`

Below is the example source data:

[image]

Expected output is at any point of time we should have the data for all the months. If any product is not present for any of the month then we have to populate the product with Zero '0' as units data.
 Below is the snapshot for the expected output.
[image]

The data should be present like the above picture.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ideally you need a calendar table to join to. do you have one available?

Comment: Good idea! See: [Building a Date Dimension Table in Redshift | Elliot Chance](http://elliot.land/post/building-a-date-dimension-table-in-redshift) and [amazon-redshift-utils/generate_calendar.sql at master · awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminScripts/generate_calendar.sql). Also useful: [NVL Expression - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_NVL_function.html)

Comment: Look at left join and how it works..

Comment: Hi all, I am already joining it with the time dimension to the source data. The query is mentioned above.

Comment: you need to cross join to the time dimension

Comment: @jon scott if I cross join the units value will be populated from the 'data' table(reference from above query) here. But for missing months I need to populate the 'units' as 0.